# Angular 2 AoT compiler: no error but something is definitely wrong

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, compilation

I've been banging my head at this for 3 days, trying to get Ahead-of-Time compilation of my `Angular 2 rc.6` application to work.

The application compiles and runs just fine using Just-in-Time compilation.

I have installed all dependencies, run `ngc` (the compiler), changed my `main.ts` to use `platformBrowser()`, and run `ngc` again.

There is no error in the console. The `.ngfactory.ts` files are generated. The `.js` files also. So far so good.  Here is my structure (it's a mess but I'll address that if I can ever get this working)

[image: directory structure]

The app runs out of `dist/`. Problem is, once I update `systemjs.config.js` and change `map['app']` from `dist` to `dist/dev` and run the App, things go downhill fast.

The first indication that something is really wrong is that whereas I expected the number of HTTP requests and the amount of data to be drastically reduced with AoT, the opposite happened. I now have 200 more requests at bootstrap!

Secondly, even though there were no errors during compilation, the app will not run. I get a `404 not found` at the path: `http://localhost/traceur`.  What? Why is `traceur` involved? isn't that used for in-browser transpilation?  Where can I start looking for what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Same,I followed the official guides with systemjs as my loader and using the UMD bundles. But that would not map correctly! So I re-configured my systemjs settings and am managing to get all the packages. But now traceur.js is the only missing package. What is that about ?!

Edit: So I mapped tracuer in systemjs, ,like so:

'traceur': 'node_modules/traceur/src/traceur'

But... now nothing shows up on my page. I believe my whole configuration with the packages is wrong to begin with though because why was my app requesting packages that weren't mapping correctly with the UMD bundles?